# Why do these two loops return different results?

Tags: python

I have a loop for calculating the total hamming distance between two strings.

For the input:

```
nums = [4,14,2]
```

One version of the loop:

```
n, ans = len(nums), 0    
for i in range(32):
        bit, cnt = 1<<i, 0

        for num in nums:
            cnt += num & bit 

        ans += cnt * (n-cnt)

return ans
```

Gives the wrong result: -84

While an almost identical loop:

```
n, ans = len(nums), 0    
for i in range(32):
        bit, cnt = 1<<i, 0

        for num in nums:
            cnt += (num & bit) > 0  

        ans += cnt * (n-cnt)

return ans
```

Gives the correct answer 6. I can figure out why?

What does the '> 0' in the second loop do? I tried to understand it's effect using a simple test:

```
>>> i = -5 
>>> i += 1 
>>> i
-4
>>> i = -5 
>>> i += 1 > 0 
>>> i 
-4
```

and the '> 0' doesn't seem to do anything. Why are the two loops different?

Comment: `>` is greater than. In regards to your simple tests `-5 += 1 > 0` is the same as `-5 += True` which evaluates to `-5 += 1`, the same as your first code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num & bit` is not the same as `num & bit > 0`;

`num & bit` is a number (`int`), while `num & bit > 0` is a boolean (`bool`);

in python, a `True` boolean is `1` when used as a number;

```
>>> i = -5 
>>> i += 2 
>>> i
-3
>>> i = -5 
>>> i += 2 > 0 
>>> i 
-4
```

as a rule of thumb, dont test with `1` or `0`; test with a random number (`2` is also bad but easy to read here);

Answer (score 1):

It's because some of the `num&bit` are bigger than 0, so (i.e there was one `8` in my run):

```
>>> a=8
>>> a>0
True
>>> int(a>0)
1
```

It's not `8`!!!

So that's why.

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
cnt += num & bit
```

you are incrementing the value of cnt by 1,2,4,8 values.

While on the line

```
cnt += (num & bit) > 0
```

first you are validating the statement, which returns 0 or 1 then you are incrementing value by either 0 or 1.

You can cross check it by printing cnt value in both the codes.